# Evaluating $\int_0^1\int_0^1 e^{\max\{x^2,y^2\}\,}\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

The integral again for convenience is
$$
I=\int_0^1\int_0^1 e^{\max\{x^2,y^2\}}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy
$$
My thoughts:
Ignoring for a moment that the region is a rectangle, I hoped moving to polar coordinates might help. This gives
$$
I=\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}re^{r^2\max\{\cos^2 t,\sin^2t\}} \, \mathrm dt \, \mathrm dr
$$
Then since $|\cos t|\geq |\sin t|$ for $t\in D_1=[-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4}]\cup [\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{5\pi}{4}]$ but not for $t\in D_2=[\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{3\pi}{4}]\cup [\frac{5\pi}{4},\frac{7\pi}{4}]$
I think we can break $I$ into 
$$
I=\left[\int_0^1\int_{D_1}re^{r^2\cos^2 t}\,\mathrm dt\,\mathrm dr\right] \left[\int_0^1\int_{D_2}re^{r^2\sin^2 t}\,\mathrm dt\,\mathrm dr\right]
$$
Aside from the problem of the region not being the same, I am stuck here. Is the work above on the right track? How do I evaluate for $[0,1]\times[0,1]$? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not use polar coordinates: Rectangles are **bad** for polar coordinates.

---

You have a piecewise definition that's making things difficult, so use each part of the domain separately. Break the integral up into two regions, above and below the diagonal of the unit square. On the lower half,

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^x e^{\max\{x^2, y^2\}} dy \, dx = \int_0^1 \int_0^x e^{x^2} \, dy \, dx = \int_0^1 xe^{x^2} \, dx$$

The upper half is similar.

Comment: shoot that was simpler than I thought. Thank you!

Comment: The upper half is similar is a bit of an understatement... ;-)

Comment: @Fabian : Indeed, the upper half is identical. $\qquad$

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

Note that

$$I=\int_0^1\int_0^y e^{y^2}\,dx\,dy+\int_0^1\int_y^1 e^{x^2}\,dx\,dy$$

Now, interchange the order of integration in the second integral.

Comment: In your first integral you've got $y$ going from $0$ to $1$, and then for each value of $y$ you have $x$ going from $0$ to $y$.  That means $y$ is bigger than $x$ in that region, so you ought to have $$ \int_0^1\int_0^y e^{y^2}\,dx\,dy, $$with $y^2$ rather than $x^2$ in the exponent. $\qquad$

Comment: @michaelhardy Yes, thank you for the catch!  This exhibits the hazzard of working on a "not-so-smart" phone while exercising in a gym.  -Mark

Comment: So you went to the gym to weaken your mind. $\qquad$

Comment: @michaelhardy Well, it was already minimally weak.  So, that should be "to maintain the already minimally weak mind."